# Are detailed logs availble in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I am running Prometheus in Kubernetes and running into some kube state metrics connection error. Trying to check logs, but unable to see the connection failure in the logs. Is there anyway to enable for detailed logging for Prometheus?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by 'metrics connection error' ? Prometheus cannot scrape the target ? If that is so, you cannot get much more than the status page of targets.

Answer (score 27):

Just add `--log.level=debug` to prometheus' startup command. Something like this:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --log.level=debug
```

Comment: `log-level` is correct

Comment: No, @mirian, log.level is correct.

Comment: Indeed `--log.level=debug` is correct

Comment: The syntax here is not quite right.  It's `args` under the individual container.  Also need to add '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` as an arg

Answer (score 12):

If you're using docker-compose, this configuration will enable debug logging in prometheus:

```
services:
  prom:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    command: --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --log.level=debug
    volumes:
      - /mypath/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

You can then check the logs with

```
docker-compose logs -f prom
```